# Clone an li and strip data?

Tags: jquery

I clone a `li` with:

```
var clone = $('#myList li').first().clone();
```

I then wish to strip out parts of the list element, so I can then refill it with new data.

Here's the list element:

```
 <li class="news-item">
     <a href="{{ $val->url }}">
         <h3 class="news-title">{{ $val->title }}</h3>
         <img src="{{ $val->thumb) }}">
     </a>
</li>
```

I do not wish to target each element by their class name as this changes from page to page and I wish to use the same cloning script. Is it possible to target them by their tags?

Also a further question.

When I use:

```
var clone = $('#myList li').first().clone();
```

I can then append it to the end of my list using:

```
$('#tiles').append(clone);
```

But I can only do this once, how can I do it multiple times? I've tried the following but it does not work:

```
$('#tiles').append(clone);
$('#tiles').append(clone);
$('#tiles').append(clone);
```

I would put that in a loop but I need a basic example.

Comment: Why do you even need to clone it if you're going to be left with an empty LI that you're then going to fill with new data, why not just create a new element ?

Comment: I dont want to create a new element as I dont want the HTML in my js, as other devs may change it's format

Answer (score 0):

You can empty an element's children:

`clone.empty();`

If you're trying to insert multiple copies of a single element you need to clone it each time, because javascript variables would continue to refer to the original element:

```
var li = $('<li />');

var ul = $('ul');
for( var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  ul.append(li.clone());
}
```

Comment: @panthro You're appending the same `clone` to the DOM, but `clone` would always point to the same element.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to target them by their tags?

Yes? The same way you're looking for `li` inside `#myList`. You can target each child element by its tag type via `clone.find('a')` or `clone.find('h3')` or `clone.find('img')`.

> how would i empty each element?

Select them, and then call `empty` on them:

```
clone.find('a, h3, img').empty()
```

Comment: how would i empty each element?